# How to create ResourceDictionary in code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:String x:Key="one">ONE</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="two">TWO</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="three">THREE</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now want to dynamically create resource ResourceDictionary same as above by **code-behind** in WPF using C#. Is it possible to create so?

Answer (score 5):

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
        rd.Add("one", "ONE");
        rd.Add("two", "TWO");
        rd.Add("three", "THREE");
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I want to create new resource dictionary(German.xml). An instance, I have two ResourceDictionary for language English and Spanish. Then i want to add another language German dynamically.

Comment: I think you are mixing Resource file with ResourceDictionary.

Comment: If i dynamically add the value into resource dictionary. the value should not save into the resource dictionary what i added dynamically in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the ResourceDictionary.Add method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms521848.aspx?